# List View – Priority Color

Tags: script-webpart, sharepoint-server

I've viewed [List View - Priority Color by Shannak](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c) and can get it to work on a task list, but not on a regular list.

Below is a sample of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: What I am trying to accomplish]

The code I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render

    var priorityFiledContext = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {

        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View

        "Priority": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);

})();

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {

    var priority = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value
    switch (priority) {
        case "(1) N/A":
             return "<img src = 'https://army.deps.mil/netcom/sites/93BEL/Style%20Library/JSlink%20Code%20for%20Suspense%20Tracking%20System/JavaScript/JavaScript/JSLink-Samples/black.png'/>";
            break;
        case "(2) Late":
            return "<img src = 'https://army.deps.mil/netcom/sites/93BEL/Style%20Library/JSlink%20Code%20for%20Suspense%20Tracking%20System/JavaScript/JavaScript/JSLink-Samples/red.png'/>";
            break;
        case "(3) Working":
             return "<img src = 'https://army.deps.mil/netcom/sites/93BEL/Style%20Library/JSlink%20Code%20for%20Suspense%20Tracking%20System/JavaScript/JavaScript/JSLink-Samples/yellow.png'/>";
    case "(4) Completed":
             return "<img src = 'https://army.deps.mil/netcom/sites/93BEL/Style%20Library/JSlink%20Code%20for%20Suspense%20Tracking%20System/JavaScript/JavaScript/JSLink-Samples/green.png'/>";
    }
}
</script>
```

I can't use calculated columns to accomplish this as the Admin guys are turning that feature off. Currently this is how I have it working, but now need to find other ways to do the same thing.

Comment: are you on sharepoint online?

Comment: No our SharePoint is not the online version.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following link for how to use jslink:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd

1. In JSLink you have to use '.js' file
2. Use JS file and remove  tag and set this '.js' file in task list so your code will be like this:

   ```
   (function () {  
       var priorityFiledContext = {};
       priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};
       priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
           "Priority": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }
       };
       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);
   })();

   function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {
       var priority = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
       switch (priority) {
           case "(1) N/A":
               return "<img src = 'https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/Style Library/PriorityColor/Blue.PNG'/>";
               break;
           case "(2) Late":
               return "<img src = 'https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/Style Library/PriorityColor/Red.PNG'/>";
               break;
           case "(3) Working":
                return "<img src = 'https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/Style Library/PriorityColor/Yellow.PNG'/>";
           case "(4) Completed":
                return "<img src = 'https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1/Style Library/PriorityColor/Green.PNG'/>";
       }
   }
   ```

   **1. Task List:**

   ### [image: Task List Priority Color]

   **2. Custom List:**
   [image: Normal List]

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati

Comment: Chandai I need to do this on a normal list NOT a task list.

Comment: @drcoz It's same code and steps for task list as well as normal list

Comment: Ok I’ll give it a try tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Still not working.  I've tried changing the view types between default and basic, still no change.  I even changed the field name to "Priority"  I've also change the field type to choice.  Still no luck.  I recall reading that if I'm not using what SharePoint sees as the field name this may not work.  When I look at the .aspx in Designer, I can't see "Priority" as a fieldRef Name

Comment: Well I got it to work on a regular list but in order to do it I had to create a new list.  It also won’t work as .js not sure why.  Also when I change the field name from priority to any field it didn’t work.

Comment: @drcoz Please tick as as answer if it 's really help to you